# Setting JavaScript variables equal to another

Tags: javascript

My JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rdvxnjon/

My HTML is like so:

```
<ul>
<li id="thing1">Kittens</li>
<li id="thing2">Rainbows</li>
<li id="thing3">Sunshine</li>
</ul>
<button onClick="butane()">Run It</button>

<p>I like <span id="thingres1"></span> and <span id="thingres2"></span>, and love <span id="thingres3"></span>.
</p>
```

Meanwhile my JavaScript is like so:

```
function butane(){
var thing1 = document.getElementById('thing1').innerHTML;
var thing2 = document.getElementById('thing2').innerHTML;
var thing3 = document.getElementById('thing3').innerHTML;

var thingres1 = document.getElementById('thingres1').innerHTML;
var thingres2 = document.getElementById('thingres2').innerHTML;
var thingres3 = document.getElementById('thingres3').innerHTML;

thingres1 = thing1;
thingres2 = thing2;
thingres3 = thing3;
}
```

The logic here is that I would like to know how to set the values of my `span` to their respective `li` ids.

Comment: Don't set the variables equal to `document.getElementById('something').innerHTML`. Just set them equal to `document.getElementById('something')`.  Then do `thingres1.innerHTML = thing1.innerHTML`, for example.

Comment: It's nott JavaScript variables, exactly you're after. You seem to want to take the content of one element and add it to another.

Comment: I would really suggest using lists here instead of making a separate variable for each item in the list,

Answer (score 1):

Just assigning it to a variable will only overwrite the value in the variable but not the content of the element.
You need to overwrite the innerHTML attribute of the element directly:

```
thingres1.innerHTML = thing1.innerHTML;
```

Comment: The assignments to the "thing" variables will need to be fixed too.